# Intermediate inequality for an inequality from Crux mathematicorum

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, alternative-proof, buffalo-way, karamata-inequality

I propose a little refinement of this [an difficult inequality from Crux mathematicorum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3848482/an-difficult-inequality-from-crux-mathematicorum) .

### Claim:

> > Let $a,b,c>0$ such that $a\geq b\geq c$ and $\frac{a}{c}\geq\frac{b}{a}\geq \frac{c}{b}$ and $b\geq a\frac{(b+c)}{(a+b)}$ then we have :

$$\sqrt{a^2+3b^2}+\sqrt{b^2+3c^2}+\sqrt{c^2+3a^2}\geq \sqrt{3(c+b)^2+(a+b)^2}+\sqrt{c^2+3a^2}\geq \sqrt{7(a^2+b^2+c^2)+5(ab+bc+ca)}$$

Proof :

First we show :

$$\sqrt{a^2+3b^2}+\sqrt{b^2+3c^2}+\sqrt{c^2+3a^2}\geq \sqrt{3(c+b)^2+(a+b)^2}+\sqrt{c^2+3a^2}$$

Rewriting the inequality :

$$a\Bigg(\sqrt{1+3\Big(\frac{b^2}{a^2}\Big)}\Bigg)+b\Bigg(\sqrt{1+3\Big(\frac{c^2}{b^2}\Big)}\Bigg)+c\Bigg(\sqrt{1+3\Big(\frac{a^2}{c^2}\Big)}\Bigg)\geq (a+b)\Bigg(\sqrt{1+3\Bigg(\frac{(b+c)^2}{(a+b)^2}\Bigg)}\Bigg)+c\Bigg(\sqrt{1+3\Big(\frac{a^2}{c^2}\Big)}\Bigg)$$

We introduce the function wich is convex,increasing on $(0,\infty)$:

$$f(x)=\sqrt{1+3x^2}$$

We have in fact :

$$af\Big(\frac{b}{a}\Big)+bf\Big(\frac{c}{b}\Big)+cf\Big(\frac{a}{c}\Big)\geq af\Bigg(\frac{(b+c)}{(a+b)}\Bigg)+bf\Bigg(\frac{(b+c)}{(a+b)}\Bigg)+cf\Big(\frac{a}{c}\Big)\quad (1)$$

As the function is convex we use weighted Karamata's inequality to prove $(1)$ :

The majorization proceeds as following :

$$c\Big(\frac{a}{c}\Big)=c\Big(\frac{a}{c}\Big)$$

$$c\Big(\frac{a}{c}\Big)+a\Big(\frac{b}{a}\Big)\geq c\Big(\frac{a}{c}\Big)+a\frac{(b+c)}{(a+b)}$$

$$c\Big(\frac{a}{c}\Big)+a\Big(\frac{b}{a}\Big)+b\Big(\frac{c}{b}\Big)=c\Big(\frac{a}{c}\Big)+a\frac{(b+c)}{(a+b)}+b\frac{(b+c)}{(a+b)}$$

So the majorization is complete we can apply weighted Karamata's inequality and we are done with $(1)$

Now we show :

$$\sqrt{3(c+b)^2+(a+b)^2}+\sqrt{c^2+3a^2}\geq \sqrt{7(a^2+b^2+c^2)+5(ab+bc+ca)}\quad (2)$$

After some basic manipulations and using [Buffalo's way](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-%28%287%28%28x%2By%2Bz%29%C2%B2%2B%28x%2By%29%C2%B2%2Bx%C2%B2%29%2B5%28%28x%2By%2Bz%29%28x%2By%29%2B%28x%2By%29x%2Bx%28x%2By%2Bz%29%29%29-%28x%2By%2Bx%2By%2Bz%29%C2%B2-3%28%28x%2By%2Bx%29%29%C2%B2-3%28x%2By%2Bz%29%C2%B2-x%C2%B2%29%C2%B2%2B4%28%28%28x%2By%2Bx%2By%2Bz%29%C2%B2%2B3%28%28x%2By%2Bx%29%29%C2%B2%29%283%28z%2Bx%2By%29%C2%B2%2B%28x%C2%B2%29%29%29) it's true because :

$$12x^2z^2-12xz^3+3z^4=z^2(3(z-2x)^2)\geq 0$$

### My question

First it is right ?

Have you an alternative proof of $(2)$  so without Buffalo's way?

Thanks in advance !

Regards Max.

Comment: I think, it's not  refinement. It's just another problem, which does not help to solve the original problem.